# Sticky Header - buggy jumping when scrolling the page

Tags: html, blogger

I'm using blogspot.com system to create my own blog.
the problem is that the sticky navigation bar causes a small jump on the page while scrolling!
this is the website if you want to understand clearly : https://www.wave4tech.net/
Also why the sticky nav is not appearing in mobile version of my site? these are my codes :

**JQuery:**

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
$(function(){"use strict";var minimumWidth;if(Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 0px)')){minimumWidth=function(width){return Modernizr.mq('(min-width: '+width+'px)');}}else{minWidth=function(width){return $window.width()>=width;}}
$(window).scroll(function(){var scroll=$(window).scrollTop();if(scroll>300&minimumWidth(1200)){$(".fbt_sticky_nav").addClass("sticky__nav");}else{$(".fbt_sticky_nav").removeClass("sticky__nav");}
if(scroll>400&minimumWidth(1200)){$(".fbt_sticky_nav").addClass("nav_offset");}else{$(".fbt_sticky_nav").removeClass("nav_offset");}
if(scroll>500&minimumWidth(1200)){$(".fbt_sticky_nav").addClass("scrolling_nav");}else{$(".fbt_sticky_nav").removeClass("scrolling_nav");}});$('.post-body').each(function(){$(this).find('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]').removeAttr('width').removeAttr('height').removeAttr('data-thumbnail-src').removeAttr('frameborder').removeClass('YOUTUBE-iframe-video');$(this).find('iframe[src*="youtube.com"], iframe[src*="player.vimeo.com"], iframe[src*="facebook.com/plugins/video"]').addClass('embed-responsive-item').wrap('<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"></div>');});$('.item-view .post-body img').first().each(function(){$(this).parent().parent().remove();});$("#navbar.navbar-collapse").each(function(){$(this).find('#LinkList1 ul li').css('cssText','display: block');$(this).find(".navbar-nav li").addClass("nav-item");$(this).find(".navbar-nav li a").addClass("nav-link");$(this).find(".dropdown-menu").parent("li").addClass("dropdown");$(this).find(".dropdown-menu a").removeClass("nav-link").addClass("dropdown-item").unwrap();$(this).find(".dropdown ul").replaceWith(function(){return"<div class='dropdown-menu'>"+this.innerHTML+"</div>";});$(this).find(".dropdown .nav-link").addClass("dropdown-toggle").attr("aria-haspopup","true").attr("aria-expanded","false").attr("data-toggle","dropdown");$(this).find(".navbar-nav").unwrap();});$('.carousel-inner .carousel-item:first-child').addClass('active');});(function($){"use strict";SearchFormInit();function SearchFormInit(){$(".search-trigger").on('click',function(){$("#search").addClass("active").find(".search").focus();});$("#search").on('click',function(){$(this).find(".search").focus();});$("#close").on('click',function(){$("#search").removeClass("active");});}
$().UItoTop({easingType:'easeOutQuart'});$('.lazyloaded').lazy();})(jQuery);if($('.archive-view .queryMessage .card, .label-view .queryMessage .card').hasClass('fbt-query-error-mode')){$('#blog-pager').addClass('d-none');};function openNav(){var el=document.getElementById("sidebar-wrapper"),$contentOverlay=document.getElementById("fbt-content-overlay"),bodyClass=document.querySelector('body');el.classList.add("openSidebar");$contentOverlay.classList.add("activeOverlay");el.classList.remove("closeSidebar");bodyClass.classList.add("sidebar-visible");};function closeNav(){var el=document.getElementById("sidebar-wrapper"),$contentOverlay=document.getElementById("fbt-content-overlay"),bodyClass=document.querySelector('body');el.classList.remove("openSidebar");$contentOverlay.classList.remove("activeOverlay");bodyClass.classList.remove("sidebar-visible");};var ppCarousel=$(".carousel");ppCarousel.append("<ol class='carousel-indicators'></ol>");var indicators=$(".carousel-indicators");ppCarousel.find(".carousel-inner").children(".carousel-item").each(function(index){(index===0)?indicators.append("<li data-target='#carouselPopularPosts' data-slide-to='"+index+"' class='active'></li>"):indicators.append("<li data-target='#carouselPopularPosts' data-slide-to='"+index+"'></li>");});$('.fbt-sidenav').each(function(){var searchWidth=$('.sidebar-wrapper').width();if(searchWidth>0){$('.fbt-sidenav').addClass('active');}else{$('.fbt-sidenav').removeClass('active');}});$(function($){"use strict";var c_form="[contact_Form]";var hide_text="[hide_Text]";var full_page="[full_Page]";var primary_button="[button_primary]";var secondary_button="[button_secondary]";var success_button="[button_success]";var danger_button="[button_danger]";var warning_button="[button_warning]";var info_button="[button_info]";var dark_button="[button_dark]";var grid_five="[full_Screen]";var grid_four="[four_Columns]";var hide_author="[hide_Author]";var hide_date="[hide_Date]";var hide_post_meta="[hide_PostMeta]";$(".post-body *").replaceText(primary_button,"<span class='post-button-primary d-none'></span>");$(".post-body *").replaceText(secondary_button,"<span class='post-button-secondary d-none'></span>");$(".post-body *").replaceText(success_button,"<span class='post-button-success d-none'></span>");$(".post-body *").replaceText(danger_button,"<span class='post-button-danger d-none'></span>");$(".post-body *").replaceText(warning_button,"<span class='post-button-warning d-none'></span>");$(".post-body *").replaceText(info_button,"<span class='post-button-info d-none'></span>");$(".post-body *").replaceText(dark_button,"<span class='post-button-dark d-none'></span>");$(".post-button-primary").parent().wrapInner('<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"></button>');$(".post-button-secondary").parent().wrapInner('<button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"></button>');$(".post-button-success").parent().wrapInner('<button class="btn btn-success" type="button"></button>');$(".post-button-danger").parent().wrapInner('<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"></button>');$(".post-button-warning").parent().wrapInner('<button class="btn btn-warning" type="button"></button>');$(".post-button-info").parent().wrapInner('<button class="btn btn-info" type="button"></button>');$(".post-button-dark").parent().wrapInner('<button class="btn btn-dark" type="button"></button>');$(".fbt-item-post *").replaceText(full_page,"<style>.blog-posts .col-xl-8.col-lg-9 {-ms-flex: 0 0 100%;flex: 0 0 100%;max-width: 100%;}.fbt-page-shape-title {text-align: center;}</style>");$(".fbt-item-post *").replaceText(c_form,"<div class='page-contact'/><style>#page_widgets .ContactForm,.sidebar .ContactForm,.ContactForm .fbt-sep-title {display: none!important;}</style>");$("#Short_Code_Options .html-widget-content").replaceText(grid_five,"<style>.feed-view .fbt-elastic-container {max-width: 100%;}@media (min-width: 1200px) {.card-columns {-webkit-column-count: 5;-moz-column-count: 5;column-count: 5;}}.navbar {padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;}@media (min-width: 768px) {.navbar {padding-left: 1.9rem;padding-right: 1.9rem;}}.navbar .container {max-width: 100%;}@media (max-width: 575.98px) {.navbar {padding-left: 1rem;padding-right: 1rem;}}.blog-post:nth-child(2n+2) .card-body .post-excerpt {display: none;}@media (max-width: 1601.98px) {.fbt-index-post .post-title.h4 {font-size: 1rem;line-height: calc(1rem + 4px);}}@media (min-width: 768px) {.feed-view .fbt-elastic-container {padding: 0 3rem;}}</style>");$("#Short_Code_Options .html-widget-content").replaceText(hide_author,"<style>#carouselPopularPosts .post-meta .post-author, .FeaturedPost .post-meta .post-author {display: none;}</style>");$("#Short_Code_Options .html-widget-content").replaceText(hide_date,"<style>#carouselPopularPosts .post-meta .post-date, .FeaturedPost .post-meta .post-date, .post-meta span:not(:last-child):after {display: none;}</style>");$("#Short_Code_Options .html-widget-content").replaceText(hide_post_meta,"<style>#carouselPopularPosts .post-meta, .FeaturedPost .post-meta {display: none;}.fbt_read_more {margin-top: 2.5rem!important;}</style>");$("#Short_Code_Options .html-widget-content").replaceText(grid_four,"<style>@media (min-width: 1200px) {.card-columns {-webkit-column-count: 4;-moz-column-count: 4;column-count: 4;}}.fbt-index-post .post-title.h4 {font-size: 1rem;line-height: calc(1rem + 4px);}.blog-post:nth-child(2n+2) .card-body .post-excerpt {display: none;}</style>");$(".fbt-item-post *").replaceText(hide_text,"<div class='hidden-text d-none'></div>");$('strike').appendTo('.hidden-text');$('#page_widgets .ContactForm').appendTo('.page-contact');$(".fbt-big-title-text").each(function(){var n="[";var r="]";$(".fbt-big-title-text *").replaceText(n,'<span class="title-sec-text">');$(".fbt-big-title-text *").replaceText(r,"</span>");});$(".post-body").each(function(){$(this).find('blockquote').addClass('fbt-shape-container').wrapInner('<div class="card shadow-lg radius-10 px-5 pt-5 pb-4"><p class="pl-5"/></div>');});$('.Blog, .navbar-brand, .header-buttons').show();$('.cookie-choices-button').addClass('btn btn-warning btn-sm text-dark py-1 px-4 radius-25 font-weight-light');});if(document.documentMode||/Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent)){jQuery('.fbt-post-thumbnail a img, .PopularPosts a img').addClass('d-none').each(function(){var t=jQuery(this),s='url('+t.attr('data-src')+')',p=t.parent(),d=jQuery('<div class="fbt-resize"></div>');p.append(d);d.css({'background-image':s});t.hide();});}
//]]>
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
.fbt_sticky_nav.nav_offset {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.fbt_sticky_nav.sticky__nav {
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}
.fbt_sticky_nav.sticky__nav.scrolling_nav {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.fbt_sticky_nav.scrolling_nav {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .fbt_sticky_nav.scrolling_nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    padding-top: 1.25rem;
    padding-bottom: 1.2rem;
  }
}
.dark-skin {
    background-color: $(header.bg.color);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 $(shadow.width) rgba(103,151,255,.25);
    box-shadow: 0 0 $(shadow.width) rgba(103,151,255,.25);
}
```

**HTML (If necessary):**

```
  <nav class='navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-dark dark-skin fbt_sticky_nav'>
    <div class='container nav-mobile-px clearfix'>
      <b:section class='navbar-brand order-2 order-xl-1 m-auto' id='header-logo' maxwidgets='1' name='Logo' showaddelement='yes'>
        <b:widget id='Header1' locked='true' title='Wave4Tech - الموجة للتقنية (Header)' type='Header' version='2' visible='true'>
          <b:widget-settings>
            <b:widget-setting name='displayUrl'>http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-dN1zT-u4E-g/YL02ix5vWFI/AAAAAAAAI4o/U32cwNmYTbg7mscXxZUN3qVdA1k175XsQCK4BGAYYCw/s305/Logo%2B2%2BEn.png</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='displayHeight'>56</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='sectionWidth'>305</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='useImage'>true</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='shrinkToFit'>true</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='imagePlacement'>REPLACE</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='displayWidth'>300</b:widget-setting>
          </b:widget-settings>
          <b:includable id='main' var='this'>
            <div class='header-widget'>
              <b:include cond='data:imagePlacement in {&quot;REPLACE&quot;, &quot;BEFORE_DESCRIPTION&quot;}' name='image'/>
              <b:include cond='data:imagePlacement == &quot;BEHIND&quot;' name='title'/>
            </div>
          </b:includable>
          <b:includable id='behindImageStyle'>
            <b:if cond='data:sourceUrl'>
              <b:include cond='data:this.image' data='{                    image: data:this.image,                    selector: &quot;.header-widget&quot;                  }' name='responsiveImageStyle'/>
              <style type='text/css'>
                .header-widget {
                  background-position: <data:blog.locale.languageAlignment/>;
                  background-repeat: no-repeat;
                }
              </style>
            </b:if>
          </b:includable>
          <b:includable id='description'>
            <p>
              <data:this.description/>
            </p>
          </b:includable>
          <b:includable id='image'>
            <a class='header-image-wrapper' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'>
              <img expr:alt='data:blog.title.escaped' expr:data-height='data:height' expr:data-width='data:width' expr:src='data:image resizeImage 240'/>
            </a>
          </b:includable>
          <b:includable id='title'>
            <h1>
              <b:tag expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl' name='a'>
                <data:title/>
              </b:tag>
            </h1>
          </b:includable>
        </b:widget>
      </b:section>
      <button aria-controls='navbar' aria-expanded='false' aria-label='Toggle navigation' class='navbar-toggler order-1 order-xl-2' data-target='#navbar' data-toggle='collapse' type='button'>&#9776;</button>
      <div class='header-buttons order-3 order-lg-4'>
        <span class='fa fa-search navbar-search search-trigger'/>
        <span class='fbt-sidenav ml-1' onclick='openNav()'>&#9776;</span>
      </div>
      <b:section class='collapse navbar-collapse order-4 order-xl-3 clearfix' id='navbar' maxwidgets='1' name='Main Menu' showaddelement='yes'>
        <b:widget id='LinkList1' locked='true' title='Main Menu' type='LinkList' version='2' visible='true'>
          <b:widget-settings>
            <b:widget-setting name='link-7'>https://wave4technology.blogspot.com/search/label/Windows?max-results=16</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='link-5'>https://wave4technology.blogspot.com/search/label/PC%20Softwares?max-results=16</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='link-6'>https://wave4technology.blogspot.com/search/label/Android%20Apps?max-results=16</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='link-3'>https://wave4technology.blogspot.com/search/label/Android%20Games?max-results=16</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='link-4'>#</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='text-1'>{ Games }</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='text-0'>{ Homepage }</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='text-3'>_Android Games</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='text-2'>_PC Games</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='text-5'>_PC Softwares</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='text-4'>{ Softwares }</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='text-7'>{ Windows }</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='text-6'>_Android Apps</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='sorting'>NONE</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='link-1'>#</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='link-2'>https://wave4technology.blogspot.com/search/label/PC%20Games?max-results=16</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='link-0'>/</b:widget-setting>
          </b:widget-settings>
          <b:includable id='main'>
            <b:include name='content'/>
          </b:includable>
          <b:includable id='content'>
            <div class='widget-content'>
              <ul>
                <b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
                  <li><a expr:href='data:link.target'><data:link.name/></a></li>
                </b:loop>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </b:includable>
        </b:widget>
      </b:section>
      <script>
```

what can i do to prevent this bug from appearing ?
i want a stable scrolling man.. i also tried to change the position to relative and to stick but none of them solved my issue.

**(SORRY FOR MY BAD EXPLANATION & BAD ENGLISH)**

Comment: In the future, instead of posting the entirety of your code, try to post only the relevant bits. It makes it easier for someone to help you and you're more likely to get more answers. It also shows that you spent some time actually trying to debug the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue causing a sudden jump when scrolling is in your css. Specifically this part.

```css
.fbt_sticky_nav.sticky__nav {
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}
.fbt_sticky_nav.sticky__nav.scrolling_nav {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

To see what's happening, in the first block `.fbt_sticky_nav.sticky__nav` try setting the opacity to 1 and visibility to `visible` and scrolling up and down the page.

```css
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
```

When you do that you'll see that when you start scrolling from the top of the page, the nav bar is hidden. Then when you get a little ways down, the nav bar suddenly pops into view. Then, as you keep scrolling, the nav bar slides up out of view. Then as you scroll just a little further, the nav bar slides back down into view again.

The thing about the properties `visibility` and `opacity` is that they don't actually remove the element from the dom. It's just hidden from view. So in your case, you have this fixed position element that suddenly pops into view but still remains unseen.

If you want something to be removed from the dom entirely, use `display: none`. When you want to show it again, use `display: block`

```css
.fbt_sticky_nav.sticky__nav {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}
.fbt_sticky_nav.sticky__nav.scrolling_nav {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
```

Note that this does break the little slide down animation when scrolling. The nav just suddenly appears without any transition. But it stops the sudden jump that happens when scrolling.

There is a larger issue at hand and it will require some more investigation on your part. Applying the fix above really only treats the symptoms of the problem. It doesn't cure it.

I haven't really got the bandwidth to dive much further into this but, I'd take a look at the jQuery code and double check your logic.

The relevant part looks to be:

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if ((scroll > 300) & minimumWidth(1200)) {
    $(".fbt_sticky_nav").addClass("sticky__nav");
  } else {
    $(".fbt_sticky_nav").removeClass("sticky__nav");
  }
  if ((scroll > 400) & minimumWidth(1200)) {
    $(".fbt_sticky_nav").addClass("nav_offset");
  } else {
    $(".fbt_sticky_nav").removeClass("nav_offset");
  }
  if ((scroll > 500) & minimumWidth(1200)) {
    $(".fbt_sticky_nav").addClass("scrolling_nav");
  } else {
    $(".fbt_sticky_nav").removeClass("scrolling_nav");
  }
});
```

Comment: oh thanks a lot this fixed it but still sometimes i see a little jump when scroll down and up (faced it only 3 times) but if you have some free time i will be so happy if you do some researches to get a greater solve.. but for now that helps a lot, user experience was very bad now it's good, and also sorry for posting the entirety of my code because i don't have language.. I'm still a student wanna study computer engineering. However thank you again :)

Comment: Glad to help. If this fixed it you could mark the answer as solved. I'd encourage you to do a little digging to find the root cause of the issue. The only way to learn is to do.

Comment: Oh u r right sir ⚡